# React Native How to send a variable to the class called by require

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In index.android.js there are lot of variables like styles, Global variable and ...

How to use these variables in the other classes in other files called by require?

example: main.android.js

```
'use strict';
var userData; //// important variable store all data
var React = require('react-native');
var PRList = require('./prlist.js');



var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ....
} = React;

var firstapp003 = React.createClass({
    _renderScene(route,navigator){
        if(route.id===1){
            return <Firstapp002 navigator={navigator} />
        } else if(route.id===2){
            return <Firstapp004 navigator={navigator} />
        } else if(route.id===22){
            return <PRList navigator={navigator} />
        }
    },
    _configureScene(route){
        return CustomSceneConfig;
    },

    render() {
        return (
           .....
        );
    }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
....
}); 
AppRegistry.registerComponent('firstapp003', () => firstapp003);
```

and prlist.js

```
var PRList = React.createClass({
    loginSubmit: function(){
    //function loginSubmit(obj,id){

            this.props.navigator.push({ id:22,});

    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>
                    PR List  {userData.display}

                </Text>

            </View>
        );
    }
});
module.exports = PRList;
```

The following variable are not defined:
React, styles, userData

How to globalize them ?